# Table of contents customization name for a newfloat environment

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, environments, newfloat

Good afternoon, everyone.

I'm using the "newfloat" package a lot, but I can't change a specific thing. I've searched a lot theses days, but I can't find anything related.
I got the following problem which consists of changing the name of a new float environment displayed on table of contents. I'd like to change the "FIGURA" name for whatever name a I want, such as, in this example "ILUSTRAÇÃO". Any thoughts?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage
[showframe, lmargin=3cm,tmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]
{geometry} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries FIGURA } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\textbf{:} }     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1,5cm}  

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\bfseries TABELA } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{\textbf{:} }     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{1,5cm}  


\usepackage{setspace}
            \newcommand\myemptypage{
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}
                \addtocounter{page}{-1}
                \newpage
            }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% Indentação na primeira linha dos parágrafos
 \setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
% Fazer isso também nos parágrafos que iniciam capítulos
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\onehalfspacing
 \setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{import}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.07855pt}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = ,
linkcolor = ,
anchorcolor =,
citecolor = ,
filecolor = ,
urlcolor = ,
pdfauthor=}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
alf,abnt-full-initials=no,   % Colocar nome completo;
abnt-etal-list=0,            % Listar todos os autores;
abnt-etal-cite=3,            % Mais de 2 nomes não são citados;
abnt-emphasize=bf,           % Ênfase nas revisas com negrito;
abnt-etal-text = it,         % "et al" em itálico. 
]{abntex2cite}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname= \hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill} ,
name= \bfseries {ILUSTRAÇÃO}
]{ilus}


\begin{document}

\listofilus

\begin{ilus}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{A tree draw example.}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{treedraw.jpg}
\end{ilus}

\begin{ilus}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{A apple draw example.}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{appledraw.png}
\end{ilus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to TeX.se! if you don't want `hyperref` to decorate links, you can just say `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` (instead of things such as `linkcolor = ,` )

Comment: To me it seems that @egreg's answer does a lot more than you asked for. Any hope of you acknowledging it? --- GOM

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, you helped a lot! Your answer really solved this particular problem. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of page 5 in the manual of `newfloat` there's the answer.

Here's a new version of your document, with several changes in the preamble, where I separated package loading from settings.

Some packages have been commented out: `babel` and `polyglossia` don't go along, the same for `tocloft` and `tocbasic`.

Look for other differences. The key is

```
% newfloat
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill},
  name=ILUSTRAÇÃO,
]{ilus}
\captionsetup[ilus]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{ilus}{%
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{ILUSTRAÇÃO }%
  \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.5cm}%
}
```

Full code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  showframe,
  lmargin=3cm,
  tmargin=3cm,
  rmargin=2cm,
  bmargin=2cm,
  headheight=15.1pt,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry} 
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % either babel or polyglossia
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newfloat}
%\usepackage{tocbasic} % either tocbasic or tocloft
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Fazer isso também nos parágrafos que iniciam capítulos
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
alf,abnt-full-initials=no,   % Colocar nome completo;
abnt-etal-list=0,            % Listar todos os autores;
abnt-etal-cite=3,            % Mais de 2 nomes não são citados;
abnt-emphasize=bf,           % Ênfase nas revisas com negrito;
abnt-etal-text = it,         % "et al" em itálico. 
]{abntex2cite}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% tocloft
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries FIGURA } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\textbf{:} }     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1,5cm}  

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\bfseries TABELA } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{\textbf{:} }     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{1,5cm}  

% fontspec
\setmainfont{Arial}

% polyglossia
\setmainlanguage{brazil}

% newfloat
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill},
  name=ILUSTRAÇÃO,
]{ilus}
\captionsetup[ilus]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{ilus}{%
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{ILUSTRAÇÃO }%
  \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.5cm}%
}

% titlesec
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}

% hyperref
\hypersetup{
%  colorlinks,
%  linkcolor = ,
%  anchorcolor =,
%  citecolor = ,
%  filecolor = ,
%  urlcolor = ,
%  pdfauthor=
}

% fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% final settings
% Indentação na primeira linha dos parágrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\listofilus

\begin{ilus}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{A tree draw example.}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{ilus}

\begin{ilus}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{A apple draw example.}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{ilus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few packages were loaded twice. Also `hyperref` should go last. Note also that it's best to load `tocloft` with the `titles` option.

I'm not sure about the explicit formatting in `listname`: you should rather define a style for unnumbered sections.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, you helped a lot! Your answer really solved this particular problem. Again, thanks!